Why can't I stack 3D arrays with np.concatenate in numpy, while 1D and 2D arrays work?
I'm working with 3D numpy arrays and having trouble stacking two of them. Here’s what I’m trying to do:
import numpy as np

grid = np.arange(16).reshape((1, 4, 4))
grid2 = grid[:, :-1, ::-1].copy()

I expected to be able to stack grid and grid2 with np.concatenate on axis=0, like this:
np.concatenate((grid, grid2), axis=0)

But it doesn’t work, nor do np.vstack or np.dstack (I observed that vstack only works on 1D and 2D arrays). I’ve checked the shapes, and I thought they’d align since they’re both derived from grid, but it’s not cooperating.
The goal here is not to reverse all rows and columns, but to only use the first 3 rows of the original grid array, with just the columns reversed. That's why I used grid[:, :-1, ::-1].copy() to keep the rows intact while only switching the columns.
Attempting to concatenate grid and grid2 along axis=0 fails with a ValueError:
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 4 and the array at index 1 has size 3
Here's an example of a simpler concatenation that does work as expected:
x = np.arange(1, 9).reshape((2, 4))
y = np.arange(4)
np.vstack((x, y))  # Works perfectly

Why does stacking grid and grid2 fail, while simpler cases like x and y work fine? Is there a specific rule or limitation in numpy that I’m missing here?

I've thought about switching both to 2d, concatenate and then switch back, but i feel there's a better way.

I get ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 4 and the array at index 1 has size 3. Is this a typo: grid[:, :-1, ::-1].copy()? What does "it doesn’t work" mean? It seems to work for me after fixing the typo to grid[:, ::-1, ::-1].copy().

@jabaa Not quite — the goal isn’t to reverse all rows and columns with grid[:, ::-1, ::-1].copy(). I only want to use the first 3 rows of the original grid array, with just the columns reversed. That’s why I used grid[:, :-1, ::-1].copy(). This should keep the rows intact while only switching the columns.

How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users? Please always read the error message before you ask a question on Stack Overflow. The error message contains all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly and answers your questions "Why does stacking grid and grid2 fail, while simpler cases like x and y work fine? Is there a specific rule or limitation in numpy that I’m missing here?"

All the ?stack fumctions use concatatenate (after tweaking dimensions - as documented). This should be evident in the error mesages.  If you change the size of one dimension, you will only be able to concatenate on that dimension. Think about what shape you want the result to be. Actions in 3d are just an extension of 2d.

In this particular case, you could use hstack:
np.hstack([grid, grid2])

For a generic case you should concatenate on axis=1 (all other dimensions must be equal):
np.concatenate([grid, grid2], axis=1)

Output:
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14, 15],
        [ 3,  2,  1,  0],
        [ 7,  6,  5,  4],
        [11, 10,  9,  8]]])

Equality of dimensions for concatenate:
grid.shape    # (1, 4, 4)
grid2.shape   # (1, 3, 4)
              #     └──── only possible dimension for concatenate


NB. as noted in comments, if your input is really:
grid = np.arange(16).reshape((1, 4, 4))
grid2 = grid[:, ::-1, ::-1].copy()

Then concatenate on axis=0 can work since the other dimensions are now equal:
np.concatenate([grid, grid2], axis=0)

array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14, 15]],

       [[15, 14, 13, 12],
        [11, 10,  9,  8],
        [ 7,  6,  5,  4],
        [ 3,  2,  1,  0]]])

grid.shape    # (1, 4, 4)
grid2.shape   # (1, 4, 4)  # any axis can be used to concatenate

